# error: use of undeclared identifier '_mm_shuffle_epi8' Ubuntu 16.04 Ryzen

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, clang, simd

So I'm getting this error while trying to compile Dolphin. I've tried clang-3.7 and 3.8 along with GCC 5.2 and 6.3. What's weird is that all the other _mm functions seem to work, it's just this one.

Comment: What other intrinsics have you tried? `_mm_shuffle_epi8` is in SSSE3; are you including `<tmmintrin.h>` or `<x86intrin.h>`? Are you compiling with `-mssse3`?

Comment: I have added <x86intrin.h> and I've tried that flag and it still refuses. I feel like I'm missing something, or if GCC/clang just hasn't enabled this feature for the Zen architecture.

Comment: If you specify SSSE3 for an x86 target it shouldn't really matter what CPU you're using; compilers have to generate code even for targets they don't actually support.  Check to make sure `__SSSE3__` is defined in the preprocessor (which -mssse3 should do).  Also, note that it's ssse3 not sse3…

Answer (score 1):

SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, which is why other `_mm` functions work (you probably only tried SSE2 functions, not any other SSE3/SSSE3/SSE4 functions like `_mm_abs_epi8` or `_mm_cvtepi16_epi32`).

**You need `-mssse3` (enabled by `-march=native` or `-march=znver1` in your case) to use SSSE3 intrinsics with gcc/clang**, unlike MSVC.

---

Note that `-mssse3` doesn't set `-mtune=`, but `-march=` does set tuning, so it's better to use `-march=native` than to just enable a couple ISA extensions with `-mpopcnt -msse4.1` or something, especially if you're only planning to run the binary on one target CPU.

For example, to enable AVX2, it's probably better to use `-march=haswell` or `-march=znver1`, because `-mavx2` doesn't override the `-mtune=generic` behaviour of `-mavx256-split-unaligned-load`, even though no AVX2-supporting CPUs benefit from it (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80568).  i.e. `-mtune=generic` always uses the fully-generic tuning settings, rather than tuning for whatever set of CPUs support the enabled extensions.

Sandybridge does benefit from `-mavx256-split-unaligned-load`/`...store`, but it only supports AVX, not AVX2.  And even then, only when the data is actually misaligned at runtime, so you might not want that if your data is aligned 99% of the time.